# Trouble understanding regular expression method findall

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing, findall

I am new to Python and my professor in school thinks that everyone understands the code he posts, but I am having trouble using the method searchnames to find a certain pattern in an HTML file. This is the code that he posted that he claims that does it. I have no clue what the symbols mean in the findall method call.

```
def searchnames(cont):
try:
    info = re.findall('(\d+)\s(\w+)(\d+,\d+|\d+)\n\s(\w+)\n(\d+,\d+|\d+)', cont)
    return info
except:
    print "couldn't find child info"
pass
```

, where cont is an HTML file that contains this

```
<head><title>Popular Baby Names</title>
<meta name="dc.language" scheme="ISO639-2" content="eng">
<meta name="dc.creator" content="OACT">
<meta name="lead_content_manager" content="JeffK">
<meta name="coder" content="JeffK">
<meta name="dc.date.reviewed" scheme="ISO8601" content="2006-03-10">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../OACT/templatefiles/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../OACT/templatefiles/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" topmargin="1" leftmargin="0">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tbody>
  <tr> 
    <td class="sstop" valign="bottom" align="left" width="25%">
      Social Security Online
    </td>
    <td valign="bottom" class="titletext">
      <!-- sitetitle -->Popular Baby Names
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#333366"><td colspan="2" height="1"></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="graystars" width="25%" valign="top">
       <a href="../OACT/babynames/">Popular Baby Names</a></td>
    <td valign="top"> 
      <a href="http://www.ssa.gov/"><img src="/templateimages/tinylogo.gif"
      width="52" height="47" align="left"
      alt="SSA logo: link to Social Security home page" border="0"></a>
      <h1>Popular Names by Birth Year</h1>September 11, 2014</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../OACT/babynames/chkinput.js"></script>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" summary="formatting">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td width="25%" class="greycell">
      <a href="../OACT/babynames/background.html">Background information</a>
      <p><br />
      &nbsp; Select another <label for="yob">year of birth</label>?<br />
      <form name="popnames" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi"
       onSubmit="return submitIt();">
      &nbsp; <input type="text" name="year" id="yob" size="4" value="2012"><input type="hidden" name="top" value="25"><input type="hidden" name="number" value="">
      &nbsp; <input type="submit" value="   Go  "></form>
    </td>
    <td><p align="center"><table width="$tablewidth" border="1" bordercolor="#aaabbb" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" summary="Popularity for top 25">
    <caption><h2>Popularity in 2012</h2></caption>
    <tr align="center" valign="bottom">
      <th scope="col" width="12%" bgcolor="#efefef">Rank</th>
      <th scope="col" width="$colwidth" bgcolor="#99ccff">Male name</th>
    <th scope="col" bgcolor="pink" width="41%">Female name</th></tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>1</td> <td>Jacob</td> <td>Sophia</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>2</td> <td>Mason</td> <td>Emma</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>3</td> <td>Ethan</td> <td>Isabella</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>4</td> <td>Noah</td> <td>Olivia</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>5</td> <td>William</td> <td>Ava</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>6</td> <td>Liam</td> <td>Emily</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>7</td> <td>Michael</td> <td>Abigail</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>8</td> <td>Jayden</td> <td>Mia</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>9</td> <td>Alexander</td> <td>Madison</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>10</td> <td>Aiden</td> <td>Elizabeth</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>11</td> <td>Daniel</td> <td>Chloe</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>12</td> <td>Matthew</td> <td>Ella</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>13</td> <td>Elijah</td> <td>Avery</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>14</td> <td>James</td> <td>Addison</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>15</td> <td>Anthony</td> <td>Aubrey</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>16</td> <td>Benjamin</td> <td>Lily</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>17</td> <td>Joshua</td> <td>Natalie</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>18</td> <td>Andrew</td> <td>Sofia</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>19</td> <td>Joseph</td> <td>Charlotte</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>20</td> <td>David</td> <td>Zoey</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>21</td> <td>Jackson</td> <td>Grace</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>22</td> <td>Logan</td> <td>Hannah</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>23</td> <td>Christopher</td> <td>Amelia</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>24</td> <td>Gabriel</td> <td>Harper</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
 <td>25</td> <td>Samuel</td> <td>Lillian</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"><small>Note: Rank 1 is the most popular,
rank 2 is the next most popular, and so forth. 
</table></p>
</td></tr></table>
<table class="printhide" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="#333366"><td height="1" colspan="2"></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="26%" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="top" class="seventypercent">
       <a href="http://www.ssa.gov/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;
     | <a href="http://www.ssa.gov/websitepolicies.htm">Website Policies
        &amp; Other Important Information</a>&nbsp;
     | <a href="http://www.ssa.gov/sitemap.htm">Site Map</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

I cannot understand how to find the rank or a child, which is ,rank, or the name,
when ever I try and run the program info is an empty set. I don't get why. Any help will be nice
This is my whole program

```
    import re
def searchtitle(cont):
    try:        
        title = re.search('Popularity\sin\s(\d\d\d\d)', cont)
        return title.group(0)
    except:
        print "couldn't find title"  
    pass
def searchnames(cont):
    try:
        info = re.findall('(\d+)\s(\w+)(\d+,\d+|\d+)\n\s(\w+)\n(\d+,\d+|\d+)', cont)
        return info
    except:
        print "couldn't find child info"
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        file = open('Popular_Baby_Names.html')
        cont = file.read()
        file.close()
        ti = searchtitle(cont)
        info = searchnames(cont)
        print ti
        print info
    except:
        print "file couldn't be found"
        SystemExit
    ranks = []
    boysnames = []
    girlsnames = []
    girlsfreq = []
    boysfreq = []
    for info in info:
        ranks.append(int(info[0]))
        boysnames.append(info[1])
        boysfreq.append(int(info[2].replace(',', '')))
        girlsnames.append(info[3])
        girlsfreq.append(int(info[4].replace(',', '')))
    print ranks
    print boysnames
    print boysfreq
    print girlsnames
    print girlsfreq
    print ranks[0] + ranks[1]

    pass
```

Comment: From a *very* quick look at the regex, it should be a **raw** string: `r'(\d+)\s(\w+)(\d+,\d+|\d+)\n\s(\w+)\n(\d+,\d+|\d+)'`

Comment: What do you want to match?

Comment: I want to match the rank boys name and girls name, which in the html file looks like this,`<td>1</td> <td>Jacob</td> <td>Sophia</td>`

Comment: The regex in findall does _not_ need to be a raw string.   The *format* as given is fine  (not saying the regex does the job, just that it is a valid regex for matching digits and words as it reads).

Comment: @GreenAsJade : Ok. I was a little worried about the '\n'; I didn't realise that you could put actual newlines into regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
<.*?>(\d{1,2})<.*?>\s*<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>\s*<.*?>(.*?)<.*?>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eF8fY4/1)

It would capture and store the ranks in group 1, boys name in group 2 and girls name in group 3.

[Explanation](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%3C.*%3F%3E%28%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%29%3C.*%3F%3E%5Cs*%3C.*%3F%3E%28.*%3F%29%3C.*%3F%3E%5Cs*%3C.*%3F%3E%28.*%3F%29%3C.*%3F%3E&.submit=Explain!&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Comment: This worked, thanks. But can you explain what the symbols mean please. No point in you doing it for me if I don't understand it. Thanks

Comment: Good on you for wanting to understand.  It is documented here:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Thank you all for the help. It's much appreciated

Comment: please don't downvote this  answer. Op stated that it was working for him. Yep, i accept the it's not a right tool, but it would work for small html files.

Comment: I agree: downvoters need to read the question title: the OP is trying to understand the RE in findall, not looking for the best way to parse HTML.

Comment: added an online explanation because it's a too long regex.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you don't want to dive into wonderful world of regular expressions, parse the HTML with an HTML parser.

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('Popular_Baby_Names.html'))
table = soup.find('table', summary='Popularity for top 25')

boys = []
girls = []
for row in table('tr')[1:-1]:
    cells = row('td')
    boys.append(cells[1].text)
    girls.append(cells[2].text)

print boys
print girls
```

Prints:

```
[u'Jacob', u'Mason', u'Ethan', u'Noah', u'William', ... ]
[u'Sophia', u'Emma', u'Isabella', u'Olivia', u'Ava', ... ]
```

Also, see a lot of reasons why you should not parse HTML with regex here:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: +1 because it's definitely the case that in real life you should parse HTML with an HTML parser.   But the OP may be forced to use RE for the class...  (in which case the teacher needs a lesson ;) )